# Default and Specific config options in hazelcast with wildcards

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to be able to something like the following with a hazelcast config (in Scala):

```
.setMapConfigs(
  Map(
    "*Foo" → specificConfig
    "*" → defaultConfig
  )
)
```

So anything matching *Foo would get the specificConfig otherwise the default.
However, this doesn't seem to work and everything gets the default config including "*Foo" maps.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast support wildcard for his configuration, in the name property.

See [the documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcard)

In xml (but it's the same with a configuration in java/scala) :

```
<map name="default">
...
</map>
<map name="*Foo">
...
</map>
```

Comment: Are you saying that 'default' is a special name? (I couldn't see that in the documentation.) In which case I should replace my '*' with 'default'?

Comment: It looks like "default" is the special name, sigh.

Comment: yes, `default` is a special case hardcoded in the method `Config.getMapConfig`